# OSM layer is blurry

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers-3

If I add the osm layer to my page it's blurry. Could some one help me to fix this? I've tried with the basic tuto from OL3 
http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection-wgs84.html

So my code is exactly the same and I am using Xampp and still have no good result. Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's blurry and it'll be blurry cause You're using reprojection - you're rescaling tiles (pictures).

The same example without rescaling is sharp:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:3857',
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

If you really need tiles in 4326 and want them to be sharp you need to use (create your own) server which will provide tiles in this projection... or else switch into some vector format (mbtiles).

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I am not using 4326 but 3857. I've the same code as in your answer but it's not sharp and that's why I don't get it! I have no idea from where the problem comes.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It has to do with the zoom of my internet browser. So if I set the pixel ratio of the map at 1 it fixes the problem.

```
var map = new ol.Map({  
        pixelRatio: 1, ...});
```

Answer (score 0):

add this properties

```js
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.de/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap contributors</a>',
            maxZoom: 18,
            tileSize: 512,
            zoomOffset: -1,
            worldCopyJump: true,
            retina: '@2x',
            detectRetina: true
        }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the zoom levels to be restricted to the available layer resolutions, so that the tile images do not need to be rescaled/interpolated by the browser:

```js
var map = new ol.Map({
  // ...
  view: new ol.View({
    // ...
    constrainResolution: true
  })
});
```